# What is the difference between "Stützung" and "Unterstützung"

Tags: meaning, difference

Both words "Stützung" and "Unterstützung" mean "support". But what is the difference in their application?

Comment: "Stützung" in rare everyday life, instead people use "Stütze".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In English, "support" has 2 main definitions:

- Support, as in giving help - "customer support"
- Support, as in holding up - "The pole is supporting level 1 of this building"

"Stützen" here means the second meaning, whereas "unterstützen" the first meaning.

Here are some sentences:

> *Wie kann ich Sie unterstützen?* - How can I help you?
>
> *Ich habe meine kranke Mutter gestützt.* - I (physically) supported my sick mother.
>
> *Wie soll ich Sie stützen?* - How should I support you (physically)?
>
> *Ich habe meine kranke Mutter unterstützt.* - I supported [helped] my sick mother.